# Permalinks: Wordpress blog built on a Joomla website

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, redirect, joomla, permalinks

Thank you in advance, here is my situation:

My website is built in joomla over a www.whatever.com domain on which the "Search Engine Friendly URL's" and Use "Apache mod_rewrite" and are ON

Now, Im building a blog on Wordpress to be placed on www.whatever.com/blog

If i write the url directly the blog appears without any error, but im having some issues with permalinks and redirections since every article in the wordpress blog leads me to something like www.whatever.com/?p=1 and just shows the main Joomla page instead of the wordpress article.

I tried some options I read on the internet but can't seem to make this work with the htaccess file.. Im not sure how to write it and where to put it in order to keep joomla as it is and the blog articles to appear as www.whatever.com/wordpress-article-name

Thank tou in advance, all help or leads are appreciated.

Pedro Teixeira

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well is mod_rewrite actually on the server your website is hosted on.

I would say that needs to be confirmed.
Ensure you've gone through this aswell: http://codex.wordpress.org/Using_Permalinks

Some ISPs don't seem to allow these:

```
The FollowSymLinks option enabled
FileInfo directives allowed
```

Also ensure your .htaccess file in /blog folder has the following:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /blog/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /blog/index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```